# GoDaddy URL forwarding while keeping relative path

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, godaddy, no-www, google-app-engine

I'm hosting my website on Google App Engine and my domain name on GoDaddy.

Google App Engine does not allow you to have naked URLs. So it doesn't allow you to have `example.com` but does allow you to have `www.example.com`.

I can easily enable forwarding in GoDaddy to forward `exmample.com` to `www.example.com` however it does not keep the relative URL path.

For example I would like for `example.com/images/3.jpg` to be forwarded to `www.example.com/images/3.jpg` and not just `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy's forwarding feature **does** preserve paths.   I have a `.org` domain registered with GoDaddy and forwarded to the corresponding `.com` domain.  Paths are preserved.

I use the following forwarding options:

- Redirect type: 301 permanent
- Forward settings: forward only

Comment: I think I recall this being a problem in the past, but working now, providing you don't select "Forward with Masking".

Comment: I have this setup on my domain and works for my main URL, but a redirect / forward *will not* keep the relative path of the original link.

Comment: @JoeFletch Forwarding for me *does* keep the URL path.   For example I have ostermiller.com set up to forward using GoDaddy to ostermiller.org.    ostermiller.com/utils forwards as expected to the corresponding page on the .org domain.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for your reply! It took a few hours for the change to be implemented. All is working as expected now!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's coming here from a search result after struggling with this issue, GoDaddy have officially said (as of 2018-07-16) that their domain forwarding no longer supports URL paths.

> Our forwarding service does not work with URL paths, unfortunately. If you want to redirect and match a path, you would need to point the domain to a hosting plan and then do a 301 or 302 redirect there. Perhaps the IP you're forwarding to can be instead set up to host your domain, so you do not need to do the forward.

https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/Domain-forwarding-path-being-lost/td-p/111686

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use *.htaccess*?

Create a text file and copy and paste the following inside:

```
# Force 'non-www' to 'www'
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YOURDOMAIN.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

1. rename it to "*.htaccess*"
2. upload it to your `public_html` folder where `index.php` is located

Comment: The hosting is on Google App engine, which doesn't have the concept of a public_html folder.